# PHP mail headers with charset=utf-8 going to spam

Tags: php

I am using the below header in PHP to send mail, But the mail is always recived in spam.

```
     $headers   = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
     $headers  .= 'From:noreply<noreply@noreply.com>'. "\r\n";
     $headers  .= "Content-type: text/html;\r\n charset=utf-8\r\n";
     $headers  .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit\r\n";
```

How to prevent the mail getting from spam.

Please help me.

Comment: You've tried without `charset=utf-8` and it doesn't go to spam?

Comment: What method are you using to send the e-mail? PHP mail function or smtp?

Comment: I'd bet that email filters put in spam because of `noreply@noreply.com` not because of charset. Anyway you don't have control which filter will put your mail in spam so the most user-friendly way is to ask your customer to check spam folder too.

Comment: i changed the noreply to info,but still i getting the mail in Spam

Comment: Maybe it is spam then...

Answer (score 4):

In general, email is classified as spam or not spam on the receiving end, not the sending end - otherwise, spammers would simply say that all of their messages aren't spam, completely defeating the purpose. Thus, you can't just force a message to go to a sender's inbox.

However, what you may need to do is see if the machine that you're using to send mail is currently listed on any spam blocklists, and if so, take the necessary steps to remove it from those blocklists. The most common is probably Spamhaus http://www.spamhaus.org/.

Answer (score 0):

```
    $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";
    $headers .= 'Cc: notifications@cityiot.ca' . "\r\n";*/
    $headers .= 'From: info@depictr.com'. "\r\n";
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$headers  = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8\r\n";
$headers .= "From: example@example.com\r\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: example@example.com\r\n";
```